# Python code with nested for loops is too slow

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm

I am doing a [problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/crush/problem) from `HackerRank`. This problem defines a zero array of size n at the beginning and then  does operations on it. So let's say that array is `x = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]`. So `n = 6` here. Now consider the operation (they call it query in the problem) `[1, 2, 5]`. This means that in the array `x`, add 5 from index 0 to 1. So `x` now becomes `x = [5, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0]`. And there could be many such operations(queries). At the end, we just need to find the max element of the final array `x`. So sample input is

```
5 3
1 2 100
2 5 100
3 4 100
```

So we need to have array `x` of size 5 (initialized to zeros) and there are 3 queries to run on it. If we go through the queries, we find that the max element in the final array is 200. I have done code using nested for loop here. Outer for loop runs through the queries and inner for loop manipulates the array `x`. 
For small values of array size of `x`, my code works good. But when `n = 1000000` and number of queries, `m = 100000`, the nested for loops runs forever (It acts like an infinite loop). I want to know how can I make this faster.
Following is the nested for loop

```
# Construct a zero list of length n
worklist = list([0]*n)
# Loop through the queries
for query in queries:
    # Since the problem defines the queries vector
    # as one based index, we need to modify the
    # indices of query
    index0, index1 = query[0]-1, query[1]-1
    # Now construct the new list with addition
    for i in range(index0, index1+1):
        worklist[i] = worklist[i] + query[2]
```

I think I need to modify my algorithm for doing this. Suggestions welcome.

Comment: You are probably interested in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_tree

Comment: @fulaphex I will look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer addresses only the algorithmic part of your question, I'm going to simplify i/o and not to implement it as a function, to leave something on which to test your skills.

The idea is, don't store the result but the cumulative delta for each position and, afterwards, find the maximum with a cumulative summation.

Let' s see the first example reported in the statement of the problem,

```
10 3
1 5 3
4 8 7
6 9 1
```

We start with `l`, a list of zeros with length equal to `n+1` (why `n+`1? because we need a little extra space to store a *delta* when `b==n`); we want to store in `l` just the *delta*'s

```
n, m = 10, 3
l = [0]*(n+1)
```

We repeat the same ops for the 3 *queries* and report the state of our list `l` in a comment

```
a, b, k = 1, 5, 3
l[a-1] += k ; l[b] -= k
# [0, 0, 3, 0, 0, -3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

a, b, k = 4, 8, 7
l[a-1] += k ; l[b] -= k
# [0, 0, 3, 7, 0, -3, 0, 0, -7, 0, 0]

a, b, k = 6, 9, 1
l[a-1] += k ; l[b] -= k
# [0, 0, 3, 7, 1, -3, 0, 0, -7, -1, 0]

current_max = 0
current_sum = 0
debug = 1
for num in l[:-1]:
    current_sum += num
    if debug: print(current_sum)
    current_max = max(current_max, current_sum)

print(current_max)
```

Executing the above code gives me

```
3
3
3
10
10
8
8
8
1
0
10
```

The first ten numbers are the elements of the summed list, to be compared with the problem statement, and the last number is the required maximum value

Comment: Thanks gboffi, it makes sense now. But is taking deltas some standard trick to attack certain class of problems ? Also fulaphex puts comment about using Range Tree here. How could that be used here ?

Comment: Using cumulative deltas is an _ad hoc_ solution for this problem, and a similar approach can be applied when you have to repeatedly apply the same operation  (albeit with different parameters) to ranges of a longer sequence.  ፨ W.r.t. _RangeTree_, well I don't know,  cannot give you an opinion.

Answer (score 3):

In the Discussions page of this problem, there is a O(n) solution there,
It's the problem about overlap.

The basic thinking is, you just need to mark "add" point and "remove" point in the array, so the final stage you only need to go though the array once and keep "current sum" in current index and you can record the max one for answer.

For example
5 3

1 2 100

2 5 100

3 4 100

your array will simplify to be

0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0

---

when take first input record (1 2 100):

100, 0, -100, 0, 0, 0

this means when you doing final scan sum summary, your loop will calculate in step

index 0, sum 100

index 1, sum 100

index 2, sum 0

index 3, sum 0
...

---

when take second input record (2 5 100):

100, 100, -100, 0, 0, -100

this means when you doing final scan sum summary, your loop will calculate in step

index 0, sum 100

index 1, sum 200

index 2, sum 100

index 3, sum 100

index 4, sum 100

index 5, sum 0

so the max is happend at index 1,

---

when take second input record (3 4 100):

100, 100, 0, 0, -100, -100

this means when you doing final scan sum summary, your loop will calculate in step

index 0, sum 100

index 1, sum 200

index 2, sum 200

index 3, sum 200

index 4, sum 100

index 5, sum 0

so the max is happend at index 1,

Comment: I don't understand. Can you please elaborate ?

Comment: the key point is you are not store the real counter array, you store a "change array", so you can calculate the final real counter array in a single loop, I've added the example, please check it

Comment: I understand the algorithm now. Thanks. But how could one have come up with such a strange algorithm ? Is this some standard algorithm ? I could never have come up with such strange way.